# Visit to USA from India via Zurich - visa needed

Tags: indian-citizens, switzerland

I am a citizen of India holding a B1B2 visa for US. I am planning to visit the USA for the first time via Zurich and want to stay in Zurich for 2 days. Will I need a Swiss visa for that?

Answer (score 5):

> You are an Indian passport holder with a B1/B2 visa for the US and you want to visit Switzerland for 2 days during your travel to the US - do you need a visa?

While Switzerland is not a member of the EU, they are a member of the Schengen Area, so to enter the country and stay for 2 days ***you will need to apply for a Schengen Visa with the Swiss authorities***.

You have no exemption due to your US visa for entry into the Schengen Area.